# LazyLoading is too lazy to Load some navigational properties

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, lazy-loading

I don't know if this is a EF Lazyness problem or real EF bug, because this irregularity only happens sometimes ( aprox. 1 in 10 times in the same code) 
The problem is that, sometimes, for some reason, some random navigational properties (not always the same) are not loaded with lazy loading active and proxy creation active too.

The example is a form with +- 40 fields that represents Person, that has a Relational connection to a lot of other tables, and that other tables, to other tables. 
I'm using lazy loading because it seems to me the best approach because of the number of tables that are involved in the Form. The problem is that some fields appear Blank, because some nav. properties not load.

The Real question is, **Is there, or anyone know a reason for EF stops lazy loading navigational properties or only loads "half of them"**?

The sample code is too complex and private(enterprise) to share here.

Comment: Usually I see this happen when the `DbContext` which was used to load the entity has gone out of scope, been disposed, and/or GC'd.  If you know the fields are required to fill out the form, why not `.Include()` them?

Comment: Thanks  CodingGorilla, this is usual indeed, i've seen many posts caused by disposed/Gc, this is not the case, i've already commented the Dispose() in my dbcontext. The reason i don't want to .Include() is because the application is quite extensive and was built on the lazy loading assumption. It would take quite a wile to Include() all correcly. Beside that, any more ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem described above was solved a long time ago by reloading the entire DbContext, after a lot of retries back then, i was able to find that the problem was, if you had some object from another dbcontext, from that moment on, the lazzyloading stops working (it makes sense now.... :P )

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a while ago.
Using .ToList() at the end of the query fixed the problem for me:

Try this:

```
using(EntityContext db = new EntityContext())
{
     db.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
     List<Persons> persons = db.Persons.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Hello, in my case is only one "Person" who does not load all properties not the list of persons, besides that i've tryed .ToList().FirstOrDefault() to get the one person, some of the properties still does not load. That's not a solution for me.